# how to get separate id for same input type while creating dynamic input filed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

js file

in the below javascript file how can i create different id for input types whenever new input type is being created.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".template_charge:first").hide(); //hide template
        var charge_count =0; // Total charge types.
        var charge_id_no =0; // To assign id and name to charge  component
        /* Add new item based on hidden template */
        $(".add_charge").click(function() {
          charge_id_no ++;
          charge_count ++;
          $('#charge_count').val(charge_count);
          var newItem = $(".template_charge:first").clone();
          newItem.find("input").attr("id", "chargeType_" + charge_id_no); //rewrite id's to avoid duplicates
          newItem.find("input").attr("name", "chargeType_" +charge_id_no);
          newItem.find("input").attr("id", "charge_" +charge_id_no); //rewrite id's to avoid duplicates
          newItem.find("input").attr("name", "charge_" +charge_id_no);
          newItem.show(); //show clone of template
          $(".template_charge:last").after(newItem);

          bindRemove();
        });

        /* Bind remove function to last added button*/
        function bindRemove() {
            $(".remove_charge:last").click(function(e) {
            if ($(".remove_charge").length > 1)
              $(this).parents(".template_charge").remove();
              charge_count--;
              $('#charge_count').val(charge_count);
          });
        }

        /* Execute bind-function at startup */
        bindRemove();
});
```

html file

Html files if for the input type which is being created whenever the add button is clicked.

```
<input type="hidden" id="charge_count" name="charge_count" value="0"/>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-12" id="other_charge">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <label for="Other_charges" class="control-label col-md-2">Other Charges</label>
                     <button id="b2" class="btn btn-info add_charge col-md-10 col-sm-12" type="button">Add</button>
                      <div class="template_charge col-md-offset-2">
                        <div class="controls" id="profs">
                          <div id="field_charge" class="form-group input-append col-md-12">
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="input form-control col-md-5" id="field3" name="charge1" type="text" placeholder="Charge type" />
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="input2 form-control col-md-5" id="field4" name="charge2" type="text" placeholder="Charge" min="0" max="100" />
                            <button class="remove_charge btn btn-danger form-control col-md-2" type="button">X</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: When an `input` element is removed should `id` of remaining `input` elements be adjusted, or remain the same ?

Comment: `#profs` element would also be duplicate `id` in document if not adjusted at cloned element

Answer (score 0):

... a bit of a guess, without being able to see the template, but perhaps the template root is already the `input`, so calling `find` returns zero length set, so does not work. Try this...

```
newItem.find("input").attr(/* etc... */);
```

... should read ...

```
newItem.attr(/* etc... */);
```